# Weird behaviour with threads and processes mixing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm running the following python code:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing

def forever_print():
    while True:
        print("")

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=forever_print)
    t.start()
    return


if __name__=='__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print("main process on control")
```

It terminates.

When I unwrapped `main` from the new process, and just ran it directly, like this:

```
if name == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script went on forever, as I thought it should. Am I wrong to assume that, given that `t` is a non-daemon process, `p` shouldn't halt in the first case?

I basically set up this little test because i've been developing an app in which threads are spawned inside subprocesses, and it's been showing some weird behaviour (sometimes it terminates properly, sometimes it doesn't). I guess what I wanted to know, in a broader sense, is if there is some sort of "gotcha" when mixing these two python libs.

My running environment: python 2.7 @ Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, threads created *by* `multiprocessing` worker processes act like daemon threads with respect to process termination:  the worker process exits without waiting for the threads it created to terminate.  This is due to worker processes using `os._exit()` to shut down, which skips most normal shutdown processing (and in particular skips the normal exit processing code (`sys.exit()`) that `.join()`'s non-daemon `threading.Thread`s).

The easiest workaround is for worker processes to explicitly `.join()` the non-daemon threads they create.

There's an open bug report about this behavior, but it hasn't made much progress:  http://bugs.python.org/issue18966

Comment: isn't there a workaround which doesn't involve blocking the worker process, as `.join()` does?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  The only reason your script went on forever in the case you liked is that the main process blocks waiting to `.join()` the thread it created.  How else can you possibly prevent a process from exiting until a thread is finished?  Same thing in the other case:  at the point where your worker process _would_ exit otherwise, simply `.join()` the threads it created.  The process was going to exit anyway, so it's not like it has something better to do ;-)

Comment: I thought that non-daemon threads would keep on running even when the thread that spawned them has been killed, regardless of any `.join()` calls. Isn't that true?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I understood it all wrong. What do you mean by "the main process blocks waiting to `.join()` the thread it created"?

Comment: On almost every OS, _all_ threads die after their creating process exits (the _thread_ that created them is irrelevant).  "daemon" or not only has to do with whether the process waits for threads to finish before the process itself exits.  In Python, part of the normal process-exit (interpreter shutdown) code is a loop that `.join()`s every non-daemon `threading.Thread`.  This is in the Python implementation (private function `_shutdown()` in `threading.py`) [continued in next comment]

Comment: [carrying on from last comment]   That's why the main process, on exit, first blocks waiting for non-daemon threads.  Unfortunately, processses created by `multiprocessing` skip normal shutdown processing - but my answer already said that ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123548/discussion-between-bernardo-amorim-and-tim-peters).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `t.join()` in your `main` function.

As your `main` function returns, the process gets terminated with both its threads.

`p.join()` blocks the main thread waiting for the spawned process to end. Your spawned process then, creates a thread but does not wait for it to end. It returns immediately thus trashing the thread itself.

If Threads share memory, Processes don't. Therefore, the Thread you create in the newly spawned process remains relegated to that process. The parent process is not aware of it.

Comment: yeah, but doesn't 'join' cause my main thread to wait for t to halt in order to continue execution?

Comment: Shouldn't the spawned process keep on going even when `main` terminates?? Isn't that what `t.daemon=False` is all about?

Answer (score 2):

The gotcha is that the `multiprocessing` machinery calls [`os._exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit) after your target function exits, which violently kills the child process, even if it has background threads running.

The code for `Process.start()` looks like this:

```
def start(self):
    '''
    Start child process
    '''
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), \
           'can only start a process object created by current process'
    assert not _current_process._daemonic, \
           'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
    _cleanup()
    if self._Popen is not None:
        Popen = self._Popen
    else:
        from .forking import Popen
    self._popen = Popen(self)
    _current_process._children.add(self)
```

`Popen.__init__` looks like this:

```
        def __init__(self, process_obj):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        self.returncode = None

        self.pid = os.fork()  # This forks a new process
        if self.pid == 0: # This if block runs in the new process
            if 'random' in sys.modules:
                import random
                random.seed()
            code = process_obj._bootstrap()  # This calls your target function
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stderr.flush()
            os._exit(code)  # Violent death of the child process happens here
```

The _bootstrap method is the one that actually executes the `target` function you passed passed to the `Process` object. In your case, that's `main`. `main` returns right after you start your background thread, even though the *process* doesn't exit, because there's still a non-daemon thread running.

However, as soon execution hits `os._exit(code)`, the child process is killed, regardless of any non-daemon threads still executing.